# Unable to use lambda in initialization list of template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, constructor, c++11

I have a class with a std::function constructor parameter.

```
class ClazzA{
public:
    ClazzA(function<void()> foo){}
    ClazzA(){
        ClazzA([](){});
    }
};
```

If I have an instance of this class as a member of another, I have to call constructor in initializer list. I can pass a lambda as an argument, and it is automatically converted:

```
class ClazzB{
public:
    ClazzA a;
    ClazzB() :
      // works fine:
      a([](){}){}
};
```

But if ClazzB is a template, lambda doesn't work:

```
template<typename T> class ClazzC{
public:
    ClazzA a;
    //works fine:
    ClazzC(function<void()> foo) : a(foo){}
    //doesn't work:
    ClazzC() :
      //syntax error : ')'
      a([](){})
      //syntax error : '{'
      //unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
      {}
};
```

The compiler is MSVC++ 2010. I don't understand what I am doing wrong or why this syntax is not supported.

At first ClazzA was a template too, and function was a bit more complex, so I thought it was the problem with templated lambda or something. But after I removed all that code the problem remains.

**UPD:** Tried to compile in MinGW G++, it works. Looks like a Visual Studio issue.

Comment: do not write "Class" prefix for class names, the code will be more clear

Comment: VC++2010 implements an older more limited version of lambdas.  They have a number of subtle incompatibilities with the latest C++0x draft.  You may be running into a problem due to this, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: The code seems correct and GCC accepts it.

Comment: Thanks to all. Tried to compile in MinGW G++, it works. Looks like a Visual Studio issue.

Comment: Funny thing. I just tried it on my g++ 4.5.2 and get and error.

Comment: @mkaes: Have you passed the `-std=c++0x` flag? g++-4.5.2 can compile the above code for me.

Comment: @aimozg: I don't have MSVC here, but have you tried `a( ([](){}) )` (add one more pair of `()`)?

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes I added -std=c++0x to my command line.  The error message is `error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token`

Comment: @mkaes: Have you `#include <functional>` and `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes both of them. I already tried playing around with some other standard headers but no change. And I already stripped down the command line to the minimum. `g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -std=c++0x -omain.o main.cpp`

Comment: @KennyTM: Forget about it. I fliped the [] with (), guess I could not see the right brackets anymore. Written correctly it works on the gcc but still fails on VS2010.

Comment: @aimozg Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you've solved your problem on your own, please post your answer and accept it here so that this question doesn't continue to show up as "unanswered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a MSVS C++0x implementation problem (see comments under question). Problem solved.

Comment: Guess this link: http://cpprocks.com/23-c11-bugs-you-no-longer-need-to-worry-about-in-vs2012/ could be useful to those looking at lambda related bugs in VC2010